# Marshaller with hyphen-seperated properties

Tags: java, spring, marshalling, spring-orm

I upgraded my spring version to newest and it seems that `CastorMarshaller` was removed from `spring-oxm` library. I replaced it with `Jaxb2Marshaller`, but there is one problem.

Previously all variables names were changed to hyphen-separated by `CastorMarshaller`. But `Jaxb2Marshaller` leaves as it is (camelCase). I know that `@XmlElement(name="hyphen-separated")` can be used and will give me the needed result, but maybe there is an easier way to change naming (don't want to replace huge FOP document)?

Maybe `Jaxb2Marshaller` properties, overriding some part or even other Marshaller?

Comment: What do you use to generate your jaxb mappings.

Comment: I'm passing generated DOMResult to FOP builder to generate PDF file.

Comment: I know that part. But you jave some XML classes, those are generated from an XSD (I suspect), what are you using to transform that xsd into classes.